# Recyclerview scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Does anybody know, how to deal with `RecyclerView` scrolling issue with checkboxes?

I inflate a view with multiple checkboxes in `Recyclerview` and after checking checkboxes when I scroll `Recyclerview` then the checked checkboxes are getting deselected.

How can I prevent checkboxes from being deselected in `Recyclerview` in Android.

Comment: do you use ViewHolders? You must store state of each checkbox in ViewHolder

Comment: Kindly post your code what you have tried...For hint In your bean class use boolean variable make its getter setter to hold its state and call notifydatasetchanged on click of check box and set the value again...

Comment: You can store the check condition of checkbox in model and depending on position set correct check value

Comment: @NikolozAkhvlediani yes i used viewHolders

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem,use setTag() and getTag() to overcome this situation.The below code will give you an idea:

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

  final int pos = position;


  viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(yourList.get(position).isSelected());

  viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(yourList.get(position));


  viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
    YourList list = (YoutList) cb.getTag();

    list.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
    yourList.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());

    Toast.makeText(
      v.getContext(),
      "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
        + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });

 }


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  public CheckBox chkSelected;

  public YourList yourList;

  public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
   super(itemLayoutView);

  );
   chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemLayoutView
     .findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have maintain this in your `List<Object>` per position and then in **onBindViewHolder** method at that position make it checked or unchecked

Answer (score 0):

simplest approach is to make a use of Model class For Example

```
class ModelDemo{

private boolean isChecked; 

}
```

In onBindViewHolder Method

```
 if(objects(position).isChecked()){
    chkbox.setSelected(true);

}else{
    chkbox.setSelected(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save checked state in holder(or in adapter) and take that info in onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder){
    ....
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(checked);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CheckBox checkbox;
    boolean checked = false;
    ...
    ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        ...
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){  
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
             if ( isChecked ){
                  checked = isChecked;
             }    
          }
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get idea from this tutorial http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

and

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html